# Specifics of varimax criterion

Tags: factor-analysis, factor-rotation

The varimax criterion maximises high and low value factor loadings and minimises mid-value factor loadings, in order to achieve the maximum value for its objective function. How does doing this ensure that the varimax criterion is a maximum value? In other words, how does having a few extreme values and many middle values that are close to zero help to achieve this? How do we know for sure that doing it in this particular way, instead of any other method, will yield the highest possible value of the criterion? Is there any sort of proof that tells us this? And is it possible for someone to prove this in a simple numeric way? Thanks!